# Skip first key in imploded array

Tags: php

I am grabbing the keys from an array and making a string from them:

```
$media = get_attached_media('image', $post_id);  
var_dump(implode(',', array_keys($media)));
```

These are my array keys: `1559,1560,1561`

I want to try ignore the first array key. Leaving me with: `1560,1561`

Comment: @nick doesn't `array_shift` kill numeric keys, leaving the OP with `0,1`?

Comment: You could still use array_shift after array_keys. But the other answer there should work too.

Comment: @Don'tPanic indeed, but I suspect `array_shift` is more efficient than `array_slice`

Comment: I think so too, but I think the most efficient would probably end up being `unset($keys[0])`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - `$media_keys = get_attached_media('image', $post_id); unset($media_keys[0]);` ? Trying this, no change so far, strange.

Comment: No, the [0] key won't exist there. The `$keys` variable in my earlier comment was referring to assigning the output of `array_keys($media)` to a variable `$keys` and using unset on that before imploding it. Sorry I phrased that kind of confusingly.

Comment: If you do `$keys = array_keys($media);`, then `$keys` will be like `[0 => 1559, 1 => 1560, etc.]` The first one will always be index 0 so it's easy to unset it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$media = get_attached_media('image', $post_id);  
$keysArray = array_keys($media);
$keysWithoutTheFirst = array_slice($keysArray , 1);

$finalString = implode(',', $keysWithoutTheFirst );
```